# How to retrieve the integer value of tkinter ttk Scale widget in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk, tkinter-scale

Could anyone advise how to retrieve and update a `Label` widget with the value from a `Scale` widget in Python? Currently it shows a very large real number. I have tried to type cast the value but this only works when I print to idle. I tried `slider.get()` but the label is blank. Also tried `int(slider.get())` which works when I print to idle.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Playing with Scales")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="24 24 24 24")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

slider = IntVar()

ttk.Scale(mainframe, from_=0, to_=100, length=300,  variable=slider).grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=5)
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=slider).grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=5)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Here you can see the very large real value:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's not a large real number, it just has a lot of digits after the decimal point, but I guess that makes it look messy. I don't see a way to control the resolution of the Scale widget, but it's fairly easy to modify the string it produces; I'll post some code shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see a way to control the resolution of the Scale widget, but it's fairly easy to modify the string it produces. According to [these ttk docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Scale.html) the Scale widget returns a float, but in my experiments it returns a string, which is slightly annoying.

Rather than setting the Label text directly from the `slider` variable attached to the Scale widget we can bind a command to the Scale widget that converts the string holding the Scale's current value back to a float, and then format that float with the desired number of digits; the code below displays 2 digits after the decimal point.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Playing with Scales")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="24 24 24 24")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=('N', 'W', 'E', 'S'))

slider = tk.StringVar()
slider.set('0.00')

ttk.Scale(mainframe, from_=0, to_=100, length=300, 
    command=lambda s:slider.set('%0.2f' % float(s))).grid(column=1, row=4, columnspan=5)

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=slider).grid(column=1, row=0, columnspan=5)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

If you just want the Label to display the integer value then change the initialization of `slider` to

```
slider.set('0')
```

and change the callback function to

```
lambda s:slider.set('%d' % float(s))
```

---

I've made a few other minor changes to your code. Primarily, I replaced the "star" import with `import tkinter as tk`; the star import brings in over 130 names into your namespace, which creates a lot of unnecessary clutter, as I mentioned in [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511018/4014959).

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: Ah, good point. I neglected to re-read the question's title. :)

Comment: Thank you. I thought I had tried adding a command to the scale but maybe not. Works perfectly; I did just want the integer :)

Answer (score 3):

An other less complicated option and easy to use alternative is to use an instance of  `tkinter.Scale()` class with which you can inject the `resolution` option to whatever value you want. The default one is the one you are looking for because its value is 1

Comment: Good advice; I was almost going to suggest that myself, but I decided to see what I could do with ttk. I've only recently installed Python 3, and I've never used ttk before.

Comment: Yes thanks for this. I did manage it with tkinter but the GUI is more modern in ttk but less documented which is why I got stuck I think.