# Why is using not() operator sometimes a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, python-3.6

This works:

```
>>> not(True)
False
>>> a = {}
>>> a["hidden"] = False
>>> a["hidden"] = not(a["hidden"])
>>> a["hidden"]
True
```

but not this:

```
def toggleHelp(self, event):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267465/showing-and-hiding-widgets#10268076
    if (self.special_frame["hidden"] == False):
        self.special_frame.grid_remove()
    else:
        self.special_frame.grid()
    self.special_frame["hidden"] == not(self.special_frame["hidden"])
```

error

```
 line 563
    self.special_frame["hidden"] == not(self.special_frame["hidden"])
                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

in the init:

```
self.special_frame["hidden"] = False
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `not` is used as an operator, not as a function. Bad: `not(True)`; good: `not True`.

Comment: The problem is the `==` operator.   Change it to `=` and the syntax error will go away.  Also, you normally don't want to use `not(x)`, just use `not x` unless you really need the parentheses for some reason.

Comment: The syntax error being caused by a typo (the two examples are *not* the same).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of `==` where you need `=`.  This normally wouldn't cause a syntax error, but in your case, you have:

```
a == not(b)
```

which is the same as:

```
a == not b
```

This groups as:

```
(a == not) b
```

and that causes the syntax error.

An assignment operator, on the other hand, has lower precedence, so:

```
a = not b
```

groups as:

```
a = (not b)
```

which is fine.

Comment: Yup... one could use `a == (not(b))` if one really wanted... but... Anyway - might be useful to link to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)...

Comment: @JonClements Yes, exactly.

Comment: The need to use `not` with parentheses to override precedence is explained in Note 3 of [Boolean Operations — `and`, `or`, `not`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not) section of the current documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you only need one equal sign, maybe that's the mistake.
`=` is for assignement and  `==` is used for comparison.