# How to set default background colour tkinter

Tags: colors, tkinter, background, default

Does anyone know the colour code for the default background? I cant seem to find this anywhere. In my program I changed the background colour and need to change it back to the default colour later on but I am unable to find the colour code.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You mean the `rgb` value ?

Comment: I just want to change the background colour to the default one. The RGB value or the 'word' value will help.

Comment: How would I know what was your default background color ?

Comment: Anyways there is a [rgb selector online](http://www.css3maker.com/css-3-rgba.html) to do this job. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you dont set a background colour when creating a button, label etc, there is a default background colour. I want to get the colour. Isn't the default background colour the same for everyone?

Comment: The default background colour in rgb was 240,240,240. I found that out using the paint colour picker.

Comment: I guess your problem is solved now.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
root.configure(background='SystemButtonFace')
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your answer could be improved if you'd add a link to a documentations on that so the user could explore the subject.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the default background at runtime, you can use the `cget` method. This may return a color name rather than an rgb value.

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

bg = root.cget("background")
# eg: 'systemWindowBody'
```

You can convert that to a tuple of the red, green and blue components

```
rgb = root.winfo_rgb(bg)
# eg: (65535, 65535, 65535)
```

You can then format the value as a hex string if you wish:

```
color = "#%x%x%x" % rgb
# eg: '#ffffffffffff'
```

To reset the background after changing it, save the value, and then use the value with the `configure` command:

```
original_background = root.cget("background")
...
root.configure(background=original_background)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is just to clear the `background` setting.
For example

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
lbl_status = ttk.Label(root, width=20, text="Some Text")

lbl_status['background'] = 'yellow'   # Set background to yellow
lbl_status['background'] = ''         # Reset it to system default
```