# Specific background color for Tk in Python

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

How to set specific color such as #B0BF1A instead of black,white,grey

```
window.configure(background='white')
browse_label = gui.Label(window, text="Image path :", bg="white").place(x=20, y=20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace it from your example. such as if you want to use #B0BF1A

```
window.configure(background='#B0BF1A')
browse_label = gui.Label(window, text="Image path :", bg="#B0BF1A").place(x=20, y=20)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [official tkinter documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#tk-option-data-types):

> Colors can be given as the names of X colors in the rgb.txt file, or
>   as strings representing RGB values in 4 bit: "#RGB", 8 bit: "#RRGGBB",
>   12 bit” "#RRRGGGBBB", or 16 bit "#RRRRGGGGBBBB" ranges, where R,G,B
>   here represent any legal hex digit. See page 160 of Ousterhout’s book
>   for details.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is compatible in python 2.7, but try this:
[Default window colour Tkinter and hex colour codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340765/default-window-colour-tkinter-and-hex-colour-codes)

The code of the accepted answer is as follows (NOT MINE):

```
import Tkinter

mycolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (64, 204, 208)  # set your favourite rgb color
mycolor2 = '#40E0D0'  # or use hex if you prefer 
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.configure(bg=mycolor)
Tkinter.Button(root, text="Press me!", bg=mycolor, fg='black',
               activebackground='black', activeforeground=mycolor2).pack()
root.mainloop()
```