# tkinter: delete a button -- keep space

Tags: button, tkinter, width

Have a look at this code example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def createbuttons ():
    texts = ["Do this", "Do that", "Hide"]
    global btns
    btns = []
    for btn in texts:
        b = Button(root, text= btn, width=20)
        b.pack(side=LEFT, padx=15)
        btns.append(b)
    btns[2].config(command=hide)

def hide ():
    btns[0].pack_configure(padx=(15,105))
    btns[1].destroy()
    btns[2].pack_configure(padx=(105,15))

createbuttons()
root.mainloop()
```

Everything works fine for me, but it seems like a newbie solution to the problem. Since the button width is a mix of pixles and character width I didn't know how many pixles I needed to add, but after trying it like 10 times it looked good with 210 pixles (105 + 105).

My question is: is there a better way to do this? Or at least a way to know how many pixles a button takes up?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to not delete your button, but draw something over it. `hide` body could become

```
f = Frame(root)
f.place(in_=btns[1], relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

Here is another answer that illustrate how to use `lower` and `lift` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928294
Another alternative would be to *draw* the frame in place of your buttons.

---

*edited after comment of Bryan Oakley, original suggestion was:*

```
f = Frame(root)
geometry = btns[1].winfo_geometry()
size,x,y = geometry.split("+")
width, height = size.split("x")
f.place(x=x, y=y, width=width, height=height)
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: you can use `relwidth=1.0` and `relheight=1.0` instead of calculating the width and height.