# Deleting a Label in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, grid, tkinter, visible

I am trying to hide everything in this function:

```
def addHome(self):
    Label(self, text = "Would you like to add to your to-do list, or generate a random item?", bg="#efefef").grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2, sticky="W")
    self.txtHome = Entry(self)

    self.btnAddToIt = Button(self, text = "Add To It!", bg="#efefef")
    self.btnAddToIt.grid(row = 4, columnspan = 2)
    self.btnAddToIt["command"] = self.addToIt

    self.btnRandom = Button(self, text = "Random!", bg="#efefef")
    self.btnRandom.grid(row = 5, columnspan = 2)
    self.btnRandom["command"] = self.addRandom
```

So that I can show the things in these functions:

```
def addToIt(self):
    #self.clearMiddle()
    Label(self, text = "Add To List").grid(row = 3, columnspan = 2)
    self.addInput()

    self.btnProcessAdd = Button(self, text = "Add To It!", bg="#efefef")
    self.btnProcessAdd.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
    self.btnProcessAdd["command"] = self.processAdd

    self.btnCancel = Button(self, text = "Cancel", bg="#efefef")
    self.btnCancel.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
    self.btnCancel["command"] = self.addHome

def addInput(self):
    #adds input for add to item page
    Label(self, text = "Name of Item:", bg="#efefef", width=50).grid(row=3, column=0)
    self.nameOfItem = Entry(self)
    self.nameOfItem.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    self.nameOfItem.insert(0, "Be Awesome")

    Label(self, text = "Item Category:", bg="#efefef", width=50).grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky="E")
    self.itemCategory = Listbox(self, height = 5)
    self.itemCategory.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
    self.itemCategory.insert(END, "Fun", "School", "Work", "Exercise", "Other")

    Label(self, text = "Other Item Details:", bg="#efefef", width=50).grid(row = 5, column = 0, sticky="E")
    self.otherItemDetails = Text(self, width=22, height=3)
    self.otherItemDetails.grid(row = 5, column = 1)

    Label(self, text = "Due Date (mm/dd/yy):", bg="#efefef", width=50).grid(row = 6, column = 0, sticky="E")
    self.dueDate = Entry(self)
    self.dueDate.grid(row = 6, column = 1)
    self.dueDate.insert(0, "06/19/2013")
```

Then vice versa when the Cancel button is hit (clearing the things in addToIt and addInput). Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove widgets or to clear values in fields ?

Comment: You might be interested in this other thread: [In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget not visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354) (especially  [Bryan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928294))

Comment: @FabienAndre I want to remove the widgets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is some way. I see you are using `grid`. So, to hide an object use `Object.grid_forget()`. 
Just in case, if you use `pack`, you can hide an object by `Object.pack_forget()`. Same thing works with `place`.

I have some idea, that might come in handy. I recommend you to have all objects you want to hide simultaneously in a single `Frame`, so you will just use `Frame.grid_forget()` instead of

```
Obj1.grid_forget()
Obj2.grid_forget()
Obj3.grid_forget()
.
.
.
```

Remember that using this will only make any object invisible, but it still exists "within" memory with all its properties.

Comment: I tried putting self.txtHome.grid_forget() and it didn't work though. Did I write it wrong?

Comment: In the example you posted,  self.txtHome is not layed out, ie you did not call grid on it, this can explain that grid_forget does not do anything.

Comment: @FabienAndre Actually the grid is called on it, just at the end.