# Tkinter: Order Widgets i.e "Send to back"

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a way to make one widget appear higher than another. So e.g a large button to appear covering all the labels below it so they're not visible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget not visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget not visible". While the answer may have that effect under some circumstances, it's not the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the common widget methods [lift](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.lift-method) and [lower](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.lower-method).