# Hide function not called

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to python and trying program for the following. I have a code snippet which outputs the label position to the shell.
I wanted to hide the label or make them invisible. But still wanted to obtain the output, even if I click without seeing them.

I wrote some code, but it stays visible.

My coding:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
def unshow_me(event):
    event.widget.grid_forget()

def handle_click(text):
    print text
    a=text
for r in range(3):
    for c in range(6):
        text = 'R=%s,C=%s'%(r,c)
        label = Tkinter.Label(root, text=text, borderwidth=1 )
        label.grid(row=r,column=c)
        label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, text=text:handle_click(text),unshow_me)


root.mainloop()
```

Please help me to rectify the problem!

Comment: Could this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible

Comment: @VincentBeltman i did the same,then also its not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bryan Oakley pointed out, you do not call `unshow_me`. However, `unshow_me` is not part of the lambda at all:

```
>>> def f():pass
... 
>>> def g():pass
... 
>>> lambda x: f(), g()
(<function <lambda> at 0x7f7737a267b8>, None)
>>> lambda x: (f(), g())
<function <lambda> at 0x7f7737a267b8>
```

The reason is that the `lambda` keyword has the [lowest precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) in Python. Adding brackets to the `lambda` body, which includes the second function in your body, and calling `unshow_me` with the argument `e` makes your `lambda`:

```
lambda e, text=text:(handle_click(text), unshow_me(e))
```

Your complete program is then:

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
def unshow_me(event):
    event.widget.grid_forget()

def handle_click(text):
    print text
    a=text

for r in range(3):
    for c in range(6):
        text = 'R=%s,C=%s'%(r,c)
        label = Tkinter.Label(root, text=text, borderwidth=1 )
        label.grid(row=r,column=c)
        label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e, text=text:(handle_click(text), unshow_me(e)))

root.mainloop()
```

Which produces the desired output (with several clicks):

[image]

However, it is worth noting that once hidden, the clicks will **not** be recorded, which is what the OP seems to want. If you want to find where the user clicks, try (modified from [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)):

```
import Tkinter
root = Tkinter.Tk()
def callback(event):
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y

root.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: good catch. I should have noticed that. The comma raised a red flag with me but I was ignoring my own instincts.