# Hide label when a button is clicked in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

How could I hide an existing Label when a button is clicked in Python(Tkinter)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget not visible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible)

Answer (score 9):

This really depends on the geometry manager you used. If you use

```
lbl = Tkinter.Label(parent)
```

to create the label, you will use one of the following to hide it.

```
lbl.grid_forget()
lbl.pack_forget()
lbl.place_forget()
```

edit (working example)

```
import tkinter

class MyClass(tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.btn = tkinter.Button(self,text='Don\'t push me',command=self.buttonCmd)
        self.btn.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nwes')
        self.lbl = tkinter.Label(self,text='Push it, it\'s fun')
        self.lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nwes')

    def buttonCmd(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.lbl.grid_forget()

root = tkinter.Tk()
MyFrame = MyClass(root)
MyFrame.pack(expand='true',fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @baited- Thanks! Works fine for me. Exactly just what I need. :D

Answer (score 5):

Use can use `grid_remove()` to hide the label.
like `self.myLabel.grid_remove()`. If you want to show it again then use `self.myLabel.grid()`. This will show widget on its original position on grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you use pack for you widget:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def hide():
    label.pack_forget()

label = Label(root, text="The text")

label.bind("<Button-1>", hide)

label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If you use place to widget
change `label.pack_forget()` to ```label.place_forget()

If you use grid to widget
change `label.pack_forget()` to `label.grid_forget()`