# How hide a label that was generated with a command button, using another button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

### The problem (Story):

I write inside an entry widget, then I press a button and a new label appear in the window with the text that I have entered. Then I press a different button and the expecting result is that the generated label disappear but, I receive an error message.

Why do I want to do this?

I want to make an interface to make SQL queries, the process that I'm trying to implement is:

- The user enters a string in an entry widget.
- The user presses a "search" button to perform the query.
- The interface returns the results. (I have achieved this using
  `LabelFrame` and `Frame` widgets).
- The user presses a "clear" button and all the widgets generated
  disappear and the interface is ready for a new query.

### The label that doesn't hide(code):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

pacienteLabel = Label(text="Paciente: ")
pacienteLabel.grid()

pacienteEntry = Entry()
pacienteEntry.grid()

profesionalLabel = Label(text="Profesional: ")
profesionalLabel.grid()

profesional = StringVar()
# Here I capture the string that I want to show:
profesionalEntry = Entry(textvariable=profesional)
profesionalEntry.grid()

def ver():
    # This label is generated without problems: 
    newLabel = Label(text="hola profesional: {}".format(profesional.get()))
    newLabel.grid()
    # When I was trying to figure out what was happening I added this:
    print(newLabel)
    # And the output is:
    # .!label4 
    # I have read through documentation why is this but I couldn't find why.


buscarButton = Button(text="Buscar", command=ver)
buscarButton.grid()


def borrar():
    # After that I saw the previous output from print was obvious why the
    # next line don't work:
    newLabel.grid_forget()

borrarButton = Button(text="Borrar", command=borrar)
borrarButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

The following picture shows the error and the GUI:

[image: Error & GUI]

### In the end, what have I read here:

- [Hide label when a button is clicked in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27654494/hide-label-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-python)
- [In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget not visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Finally if you are reading this question, thanks for your time!

Comment: Why do you hide as opposed to destroying?

Comment: How exactly is the title in 3rd or 5th [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49210436/revisions) the better one grammatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `global newLabel` as the first line to `def ver():` but that would let you only hide the very last label you've created, *unrecursively*. The reason for that is that you have no reference left for the former label objects, but they still exist, but they cannot exactly easily be referenced. Instead, I'll provide an answer that answers:

> *"How to hide a label that was generated with a command button, using another button?"*

One can do all kinds of things to a widget(label is a widget) so long as they have a valid reference(your `newLabel` reference gets overwritten). It doesn't matter how they are created, so long as they have the reference. In the example below, there's a `button_that_creates_labels`, a `button_that_hides_labels`, an `entry` that lets the user set the new label's text. The `button_that_hides_labels` hides the last label added, *recursively*:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def create_new_label(parent, widget_list, entry, button):
    widget_list.append(tk.Label(parent, text=entry.get()))
    widget_list[-1].grid(columnspan=2)
    button['command'] = lambda w=widget_list, i=-1, b=button: \
        hide_the_last_label(w, i, b)


def hide_the_last_label(widget_list, index, button):
    if len(widget_list) >= abs(index):
        widget_list[index].grid_remove()
        button['command'] = lambda w=widget_list, i=index-1, b=button: \
            hide_the_last_label(w, i, b)


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    # This list will contain all widgets objects generated during the
    # execution of the lambda expression.
    labels = list()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    button_that_hides_labels = tk.Button(root, text="Hide")
    # A lambda expression to prevent call the function before the
    # button has been pressed.
    button_that_creates_labels = tk.Button(root, text="Create",
        command=lambda p=root, wl=labels, e=entry, b=button_that_hides_labels\
                                            : create_new_label(p, wl, e, b))
    button_that_hides_labels['command'] = lambda w=labels, i=-1, \
                    b=button_that_hides_labels:hide_the_last_label(w, i, b)
    button_that_creates_labels.grid(row=1, column=0)
    button_that_hides_labels.grid(row=1, column=1)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

However, if you wanted to destroy & delete instead of just hiding, my implementation would've been much simpler:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


def create_new_label(parent, widget_list, entry):
    widget_list.append(tk.Label(parent, text=entry.get()))
    widget_list[-1].grid(columnspan=2)


def remove_the_last_label(widget_list):
    if widget_list:
        # Here the widget don't show up
        widget_list[-1].destroy()
        # If the item is not removed from the list, white spaces will remain
        # in the window.
        del widget_list[-1]


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    labels = list()
    entry = tk.Entry(root)
    button_that_hides_labels = tk.Button(root, text="Hide")
    button_that_creates_labels = tk.Button(root, text="Create",
        command=lambda p=root, wl=labels, e=entry: create_new_label(p, wl, e))
    button_that_hides_labels['command'] = lambda w=labels: \
                                                    remove_the_last_label(w)
    button_that_creates_labels.grid(row=1, column=0)
    button_that_hides_labels.grid(row=1, column=1)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
    tk.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your solution worked perfect. I will add some comments to your code just for clarifying and check if I understood well how the code works. I have to ask, where can I find more info about "objects references" in "tkinter or working with callbacks in tkinter"? I have found many "follow this recipe in tkinter" but no many articles that explain how the things works. In a few days I will post a repo in github with my "db browser gui".

Comment: @Venguiat Object references and callbacks can be read about Python as well. They're not specific to tkinter. You may want to read about callbacks for tkinter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6920302/7032856) perhaps.