# Clear whole root

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and I was wondering if there is a way to clear whole root (window). I tried with `root.destroy()` , but I want to have a chance to undo(to callback some widgets). I also tried `.pack_forget()` and `.grid_forget()` , but it takes a lot of time and later may cause many bugs in program.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you tried .grid_remove()?

Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible/5928294#5928294)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan on literally destroying everything in the root window, my recommendation is to make a single frame be a child of the root window, and then put everything inside that frame. Then, when you need to clear the root window you only have to delete this one widget, and it will take care of deleting all of the other widgets.

If instead of destroying the widgets you want to merely hide them, the best solution is to use `grid`, so that you can use `grid_forget` to remove them from view, and `grid` to make them visible again. You can use `pack` and `pack_forget`, but `pack` doesn't remember where the widget was, making it more difficult to restore them without a lot of work.

If your program is made of logical groups of widgets, use frames to create the groups, and then you can `destroy` or call `grid_forget` on the entire frame at once, rather than having to do that for each individual widget.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never remember to put my widgets into groups with frames.

Answer (score 2):

```
for ele in root.winfo_children():
  ele.destroy()
```

Comment: Helpful if explain you answer instead of code only.

Comment: So root is the master object. root.winfo_children() lists all the child weights in the root, and by giving the command .destroy to every weight, you basically clean up the entire root