# Python: Z-index on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Does exist a way to specificate the depth of an element of the Tkinter canvas, like the HTML's z-index?

Currently the only way I found to let the element overlap as I want is to create it in a specific order; the problem is that some element must be created after Others, but they also should have a lower z-index.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: ~~I don't think so, but all tkinter widgets have a `tkraise()` method to bring them to the top, so you could create all your widgets and then raise them in the correct order.~~ Edit: Oh nm; I missed that you are working with elements on a canvas.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429459/lift-and-raise-a-canvas-over-a-canvas-in-tkinter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, all elements on a canvas are in a stacking order. They can be manipulated with the [tag_raise](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_raise-method) and [tag_lower](https://dafarry.github.io/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_lower-method) methods.

For a rudimentary layering system see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576938/7432