# How to hide and show canvas items on tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I know that `pack` and `pack_forget` can be used to show or hide widgets. Which are the equivalent commands for items on a canvas?

Notice: It would be better to keep the complete item information, including its position. This is not the case with `pack`/`pack_forget`, where you need to inform the position again whenever you use pack.

Comment: Try [canvas.itemconfigure(id, state='hidden'/'normal')](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M119)

Comment: It was exactly what I needed, thanks. I wonder why you didn't submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by @CommonSense, you can [toggle hide/show](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M119) canvas items using:

`canvas.itemconfigure(id, state='hidden'/'normal')`

from [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible#comment13203758_3819568) on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible), you get a similar functionality for widgets positioned with the `grid` geometry manager:

> `grid_remove` is another option. It's advantage over `grid_forget` is that
>   `grid` will remember all of the options, so that a simple `grid()` will
>   put it right back. There is no pack_remove

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
canvas.itemconfigure(id, state='hidden'/'normal')
```

as mentioned in @Reblochon Masque answer although attention to the id. this id is the return value of the widget placement method

```
id = parent.create_window(x, y, window=my_widget_name)
```

not the widget's name