# How to shrink a frame in tkinter after removing contents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-layout

Most of the topics I came across deals with how to *not* shrink the `Frame` with contents, but I'm interested in shrinking it back after the destruction of said contents.  Here's an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text='Hello!')
lbl1.pack()
frm = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frm.pack()
lbl3 = tk.Label(root, text='Bye!')
lbl3.pack()
lbl2 = tk.Label(frm, text='My name is Foo')
lbl2.pack()
```

So far I should see this in my window:

```
Hello!
My name is Foo
Bye!
```

That's great, but I want to keep the middle layer interchangeable and hidden based on needs.  So if I destroy the `lbl2` inside:

```
lbl2.destroy()
```

I want to see:

```
Hello!
Bye!
```

But what I see instead:

```
Hello!
███████
Bye!
```

I want to shrink `frm` back to basically non-existence because *I want to keep the order of my main widgets intact*.  Ideally, I want to run `frm.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)` so that my widgets inside can scale accordingly.  However if this interferes with the shrinking, I can live without `fill/expand`.

I've tried the following:

1. `pack_propagate(0)`: This actually doesn't expand the frame at all past `pack()`.
2. Re-run `frm.pack()`: but this ruins the order of my main widgets.
3. `.geometry('')`: This only works on the `root` window - doesn't exist for `Frame`s.
4. `frm.config(height=0)`: Oddly, this doesn't seem to change anything at all.
5. `frm.pack_forget()`: [From this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible), however it doesn't bring it back.

The only option it leaves me is using a `grid` manager, which works I suppose, but not exactly what I'm looking for... so I'm interested to know if there's another way to achieve this.

Comment: @stovfl thanks for the suggestion, but this is just my [mre].  My real examples have a bunch of varying widgets within the `frm` that requires more controls.  Some are `Label`s, `LabelFrame`s, `Button`s... etc...

Comment: The code in your question is **not** a [mre].

Comment: @martineau Could you please clarify? The code in my question produces the result I'm experiencing that I want to change.  If you mean I should include all my other widgets in there it'd hardly be a minimal example?

Comment: ***"the same height required by the Label"***: Count it by yourself, looping `frm.children ; <child ref>.winfo_height()`

Comment: @stovfl after `lbl2.destroy()`, there's nothing in `frm.children` though.  I understand that by creating `lbl2` within `frm` it expanded the size, but I'm wondering if there's a built-in method I'm overlooking that undoes it.

Comment: @r.ook ***"after `lbl2.destroy()`, there's nothing "***: Yes in your example it's nothing which results in `height == 0`. But you claim you have other widgets which get in count.

Comment: My other widgets are in my real codebase, which in the interest of minimal representation, I didn't include here.  But I digress - even with this example, after `lbl2` is removed, the height is not `0`, and therefore the `frm` doesn't shrink back.  There's nothing else in the `frm` that should take up height, and yet it won't shrink.

Comment: r.ook:  I meant it's incomplete in the sense that it cannot be run standalone to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Question**: Shrink a `Frame` after removing the **last** widget?

Bind to the `<'Expose'>` event and `.configure(height=1)` if no children.

---

**Reference**:

- [Expose](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/bind.htm#M15)

  > An Expose event is generated whenever all or part of a widget should be redrawn

---

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        tk.Label(self, text='Hello!').pack()
        self.frm = frm = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frm.pack()
        tk.Label(self, text='Bye!').pack()
        tk.Label(frm, text='My name is Foo').pack()

        self.menubar = tk.Menu()
        self.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.menubar.add_command(label='delete', command=self.do_destroy)
        self.menubar.add_command(label='add', command=self.do_add)

        frm.bind('<Expose>', self.on_expose)

    def do_add(self):
        tk.Label(self.frm, text='My name is Foo').pack()
        
    def do_destroy(self):
        w = self.frm
        if w.children:
            child = list(w.children).pop(0)
            w.children[child].destroy()

    def on_expose(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        if not w.children:
            w.configure(height=1)
        
                            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

---

> **Question**: Re-run `frm.pack()`: but this ruins the order of my main widgets.
> `frm.pack_forget()`, however it doesn't bring it back.

`Pack` has the options `before=` and `after`. This allows to pack a widget relative to other widgets.

---

**Reference**:

- [-before](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TkCmd/pack.htm#M9)

  > Use its master as the master for the slaves, and insert the slaves just before other in the packing order.

---

Example using `before=` and `self.lbl3` as anchor. The `Frame` are removed using  `.pack_forget()` if no children and get repacked at the same place in the packing order.

> Note: I show only the relevant parts!

```
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.frm = frm = tk.Frame(self, bg='black')
        frm.pack()
        self.lbl3 = tk.Label(self, text='Bye!')
        self.lbl3.pack()
        ...

    def on_add(self):
        try:
            self.frm.pack_info()
        except:
            self.frm.pack(before=self.lbl3, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        tk.Label(self.frm, text='My name is Foo').pack()

    def on_expose(self, event):
        w = event.widget
        if not w.children:
            w.pack_forget()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.5 - 'TclVersion': 8.6 'TkVersion': 8.6***

Comment: This code won't run as posted - `NameError: name 'Application' is not defined`. Also, on OSX you can't put commands directly on the menubar. Otherwise, it's a cool solution.

Comment: @BryanOakley: *code won't run*. Fixed, `import ...` also missing. * put commands directly on the menubar*: How does it look on OSX?

Comment: On OSX the commands simply don't show up at all. OSX silently ignores them. All commands must be on dropdown menus.

Answer (score 4):

When you destroy the last widget within a frame, the frame size is no longer managed by `pack` or `grid`. Therefore, neither `pack` nor `grid` knows it is supposed to shrink the frame.

A simple workaround is to add a small 1 pixel by 1 pixel window in the frame so that `pack` still thinks it is responsible for the size of the frame.

Here's an example based off of the code in the question:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text='Hello!')
lbl1.pack()
frm = tk.Frame(root, bg='black')
frm.pack()
lbl3 = tk.Label(root, text='Bye!')
lbl3.pack()
lbl2 = tk.Label(frm, text='My name is Foo')
lbl2.pack()

def delete_the_label():
    lbl2.destroy()
    if len(frm.winfo_children()) == 0:
        tmp = tk.Frame(frm, width=1, height=1, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)
        tmp.pack()
        root.update_idletasks()
        tmp.destroy()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Delete the label", command=delete_the_label)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is there not a way to make the frame 0 by 0?

Comment: @GT77: no, I don't think it's possible to create a zero-width frame.