# How do I make childless frame disappear?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a root with a red menu and a blue frame (the blue frame is the frame the question is referring to). One button is to destroy everything on the blue frame, and the other is to check if there are any children remaining on the blue frame (just to make sure everything is indeed gone).

```
import tkinter as tk

def destroy_everything():
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()

root = tk.Tk()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "blue")
frame.pack()

tk.Label(frame, width = 20, height = 20, text = "hello").pack()

menu = tk.Frame(root, height = 30, bg = "red")
menu.pack(fill = tk.X)

tk.Button(menu, command = destroy_everything, text = "X").pack(side = tk.LEFT)
tk.Button(menu, command = lambda: print(frame.winfo_children())).pack(side = tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Initially, the blue frame spawns in with a label, but the blue frame stays when the label gets deleted despite the blue frame now not having any children on it. I thought frames turn into sizes of 1x1/become invisible when without children and not given a fixed size.

I don't want the frame to go away necessarily since I want to use it again but I wish it weren't so visible when empty.

Simply put, are frames supposed to remain after its last child gets deleted with a "shadow" of is former contents?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shrink a frame in tkinter after removing contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59584847/how-to-shrink-a-frame-in-tkinter-after-removing-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought frames turn into sizes of 1x1/become invisible when without children and not given a fixed size.

No, that's not what happens. When you remove the last widget, then there's no geometry manager managing the frame so it won't revert to 1x1 pixels.

You can directly configure the size with `configure` if you wish:

```
frame.configure(width=1, height=1)
```

Or, if you know how `frame` was added to its parent, you can call the appropriate `forget` method:

```
frame.pack_forget()
```