# Switching between differently sized Frames

Tags: python, tkinter, layout

How can I make these pages two different sizes?  Say I want to make `StartPage` large, 500 x 500, and  `New_Card_Page` small, say 100 x 100.  `App.geometry("200x200")` changes all pages, which is not what I want.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
LARGE_FONT=('Verdana', 12)

class Index_Cards_App(Tk):   
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)            
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)    
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)        
        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, New_Card_Page):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()     
        
class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label=Label(self, text='Index Cards')  
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)               
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Enter New Card', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(New_Card_Page))
        button1.pack()      
        
class New_Card_Page(Frame): 
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label=ttk.Label(self, text='Enter New Card') 
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)          
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text='Back to Home', command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack() 
        
app=Index_Cards_App()
app.geometry("200x200")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: The technique you're using to display different pages is based on "raising" one of them to the top to make it visible, and was designed assuming they all have the same size and will completely cover one another. You'll need to do things some other way to do what you say you  want.

Comment: Thanks martineau

Comment: You may be able to control the visibility of each page another way. See [In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget not visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-not-visible)

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you copied works by stacking all of the pages on top of each other, and assumes they are all the same size. It's not exactly a great design, especially if you're just learning tkinter.

If you want each page to have its own size, the easiest solution is to remove the use of `grid` when the pages are initially created, and instead have `show_frame` remove the current page and add the new page.

First, create an attribute to hold the current page so that it can be removed, and remove the call to `grid` inside the loop in `__init__`. Also, since we're not going to rely on stacking the pages on top of each other we can remove commands to configure the grid.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    container = Frame(self)
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
    self.current_frame = None
    self.frames = {}
    for F in (StartPage, New_Card_Page):
        frame = F(container, self)
        self.frames[F] = frame
    self.show_frame(StartPage)
```

Next, modify `show_frame` to hide the current page and show the new page. Since we're no longer stacking widgets on top of each other, `pack` is a simpler choice than `grid`:

```
def show_frame(self, cont):
    if self.current_frame is not None:
        self.current_frame.pack_forget()
    self.current_frame = self.frames[cont]
    self.current_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Finally, remove the call to `geometry` at the end of your code, since that forces the window to a specific size.

With those changes, each page will cause the window to resize to fit the current page.