# Button hide/show

Tags: python, tkinter, button, canvas

I am currently trying to create a button that can be hidden or shown with a definition (def).

```
root.Tk()
c = Canvas(root, wodth=1600, Height=100, bg='black')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
c.pack
b = Button(c, text='I want to be unvisiblie')
b.place(x=210, y=88)

root.after(1)
```

Could you help me, Please? How can I do this (Please without any self-command)?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819568/12203337) on how to hide buttons and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928294/12203337) on how to make elements visible again.

Comment: I recommend you take a tutorial on `tkinter` first.

Comment: Once you click the button, the button would hide, how do you plan on bringing it up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So...
You can use the "place_forget" to hide any widget..

So this is what can help you!

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
a_button = Button(c, text='I want to by unvisiblie', command = lambda:b.place_forget())# I think the text should be "I want to be invisible!"
a_button.place(x=210, y=88)
root.mainloop()
```

I hope that you wanted this answer