# How to open a new window in tkinter python with the click of a button while simultaneously closing the old window

Tags: python, function, class, tkinter, tk-toolkit

In Python, I'm trying to make an App, so after logging in, a new window is created, to delete the previous window I have tried to use .destroy() or .exit(), but along with the old window, even the new window gets deleted...can someone please help me?

Comment: You are using `tk.Toplevel` right? Destroying the main window destroy all TopLevel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819354/in-tkinter-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-widget-invisible In Tkinter is there any way to make a widget invisible?

Answer (score 0):

Assume your code is like this:
`import tkinter as tk root1 = tk.Tk() button = tk.Button(root1,text="Open Window",command=onclick)`
Then you can do it like this:
`def onlick(): root2 = tk.Tk() root1.destroy()` 
And whatever widgets you want inside the new window need their master attribute set to "root2" like this:
`label = tk.Label(root2,text='this is a new window')`

I hope this helps!